# Is this php code sanitization redundant or incorrect?

Tags: php, forms, sanitization

Let's say  this code is executed after press the submit button in a form with purposes of sanitization:

```
<?php
$yourname = check_input(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'yourname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$email = check_input(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
$likeit = check_input(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'likeit', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$comments = check_input(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comments', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data) . stripslashes($data) . htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Taking in account that the filter_input function is being applied, is the check_input($data) function redundant in this case?

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's excessive and wrong! Understand what each of these functions like [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) actually does, and where it' appropriate to use it, rather than simply using throwing them into the function without understanding

Comment: Context is good to know here, what do you intend to do with the collected data?

Comment: Protecting form from hack and spam, of course

Comment: Sometimes filters don't perhaps act as you'd expect.  `filter_var('foo(this is just a comment)@example.com', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);`, will break, what is, a valid address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current code of the `check_input` function is pretty useless: You get the input back concatenated 3 times but with different filters applied

```
function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data) . stripslashes($data) . htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

---

Regarding `filter_input()`: Using `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` should be enough. From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

> Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters.

This is basically what you intended with your own function.

---

Don't forget to watch out for SQL injection attacks. Using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) as intended will keep you on the safe side.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So the result will be like this:

Comment: <?php
$yourname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'yourname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$likeit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'likeit', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$comments = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comments', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>